# Paste special for .NET 4.5 only?

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using the VS 2013 IDE tool Edit->Paste special->Paste XML as classes. One of the requirements for this to be available is that the target framework will be 4.5.

Will the class generated this way work in a FW4.0 project? Will this class support serialize/deserialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code itself is .NET 2 compatible. It uses the XML framework classes that have been there since .NET 2.

The *Paste Special* option is just a Visual Studio IDE feature, it isn't specifically related to .NET 4.5.

> Will this class support serialize/deserialize?

Yes, it will just serialize/deserialize like you expect. You can use [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for that job, which has been there since .NET 1.1.

Comment: Then why it matters which FW the project targets?

Comment: Good question. I see no use for that.